# Configure awsvpc containers to have internet access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ecs

I have containers configured to use [awsvpc](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-ecs-introduces-awsvpc-networking-mode-for-containers-to-support-full-networking-capabilities/) network mode. Each task has its own ENI, so essentialy they are kind of "EC2 instances" that have no public IP. I also use WebSockets (socket.io), so I need my LoadBalancer/NAT Gateway to work with WebSockets (utilize sticky sessions). So my question is:

**How to configure something with an ENI that has only private IP to have access to the Internet *(with sticky sessions)*?**

Answer (score 0):

create a aws NLB (Which supports wss)

and then create a ecs service in that wizard you can add the network load balancer